# Is the set of the irreducible elements of a field empty?

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra

> The set of the irreducible elements of a field is empty.

I'm confused with this affirmatiom.

Let's take for example ℚ. Every elements is unit, so every element is a product of unit elements. Every element is irreducible then ?

Comment: I've only seen "reducible" and "irreducible" applied to non-units.  I don't think the concept makes sense for units.

Comment: What is your definition of irreducible? All references I know define irreducible to non-zeros non-unity.

Comment: An element e in A is irreducible if 
1) e is not a unit in A (e is not invertible in A),
2) if e = ab, then a or b is a unit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An irreducible element is a nonzero nonunit element $x$ such that if $x=ab$ for some nonunit $a$, then $b$ is a unit. In a field there are no nonzero, nonunit elements, so there are no irreducible elements.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I forgot the first condition of a nonunit element x. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a non-zero non-unit element in an integral domain is called irreducible if it is not a product of two non-units. 
But in a field, all non-zero elements are units. So there are no irreducible elements in a field.